# Getting a frame from video but bigger than the mini thumbnail

Tags: android, thumbnails, video-recording

I am using the commonsware cwac library to record a video and I want to display the thumbnail of the video to the user, however, the available thumbnail function provided by Android gives only two option micro and mini and both of them give very small thumbnails. is there a way to get a frame from the video with larger dimensions.

Comment: Find some code that can extract an actual frame from the video itself. FFMPEG may be able to do this.

Comment: I try to minimize the usage of third party libraries as much as possible. most of them contain more than required.

Comment: Then live with the thumbnails Android gives you. Or write your own MP4 decoder from scratch, or something.

Comment: I found it actually. using the MediaMetadataRetriever is one of the best Android alternatives to the standard thumbnails. I guess I won't have to live with what I used to have anymore. Thank you for the interesting reply ;)

Comment: My apologies for thinking that `MediaStore` was the only source of frames.